# inserting random number into hidden field on submit

Tags: javascript, forms

Trying to insert a random number into a hidden field in a form using javascript. Not passing any value since SQL error of - doesn't have a default value

```js
var randomNum = '';
    randomNum += Math.round(Math.random()*5);
var elem = document.getElementById("randSS").value = randomNum;
```

```html
<input name="randSS" type="text" id="randSS"/>
```

Comment: There's no question and everything appears to work.

Comment: Agree with @PatrickRoberts. Also, you have `var elem` initialized with a `randomNum`, not with actual HTMLElement.

Comment: Ok then maybe my issue is Laravel is not passing the value, I see it working as well but still getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'randSS' doesn't have a default value even with strict mode off

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have protected fillable added!